# Python Selenium - how to access methods from different modules using the same webdriver instance

Tags: python, selenium, inheritance, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am getting very confused and was hoping someone here could help me out.

So here is my scenario: I have one module containing the Base class where the webdriver instance is created and this will be inherited by all tests; a separate module containing a class that will be inherited by all tests for a specific page (let's call that page engagements); and a separate module for opening a different webpage (let's call it reports). I created another module with tests that will access the engagements page and the reports page.

When I try to access the methods under the reports module, it always fails. The reason is when I tried to access the methods, it was not using the webdriver instance that was created by the autouse fixture (which is in the Base class).

I got it working by multiple inheritance here:

This is base.py

```
class Base:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True):
    def _init_browser(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

This is base_engagements.py

```
class BaseEngagements(Base):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def login_engagements(self):
        print("login for engagements goes here")
```

This is engagement_reports.py

```
class CheckReportsPage(Base):
    def open_reports_for_engagement(self, voice_name):
        print("opening reports")
        self.browser.find_element_by_id("report_name")
```

And this is the test under test_voice_engagement.py

```
class TestVoice(BaseEngagements, CheckReportsPage):
    def test_open_reports_for_voice(self, voice_name):
        self.open_reports_for_engagement(voice_name)
```

However, I would like to avoid multiple inheritance in the test module, for the main reason that more tests will have to use methods from other modules which are for specific webpages.

Is there a way to avoid multiple inheritance in this scenario?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid **multiple inheritance** you could use **composition**.
This article explains inheritance vs composition in nice way with example
https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html

**Note** - *Answer is generic to python and not specific to Pytest or Selenium*

**Inheritance way** *Child is inheriting Parent*

```
class Parent(object):

    def override(self):
        print "PARENT override()"

    def implicit(self):
        print "PARENT implicit()"

    def altered(self):
        print "PARENT altered()"

class Child(Parent):

    def override(self):
        print "CHILD override()"

    def altered(self):
        print "CHILD, BEFORE PARENT altered()"
        super(Child, self).altered()
        print "CHILD, AFTER PARENT altered()"
```

**Composition way** Child in not inheriting Parent, rather creating another object of parent during its `init`. So child contains a parent object and have access to all methods of parents via this objct.

```
class Other(object):

    def override(self):
        print "OTHER override()"

    def implicit(self):
        print "OTHER implicit()"

    def altered(self):
        print "OTHER altered()"

class Child(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.other = Other()

    def implicit(self):
        self.other.implicit()

    def override(self):
        print "CHILD override()"

    def altered(self):
        print "CHILD, BEFORE OTHER altered()"
        self.other.altered()
        print "CHILD, AFTER OTHER altered()"
```

Comment: I did try composition before but it failed everytime because when CheckReportsPage object was created, there was no browser instance, so I kept getting an attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the methods from CheckReportsPage by adding a constructor to it and passing a browser instance when calling it. It basically looked like this:

```
class CheckReportsPage(Base):
    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser
```

So in TestVoice I did this:

```
def test_open_reports_for_voice(self, voice_name):
    self.reports = CheckReportsPage(self.wd)
    self.reports.open_reports_for_engagement(voice_name)
```

This works for me, but there might be a better way, haven't found it yet :)